# ffmpeg not producing duration value when converting a media file. If this media is used in an html player, seeking fails on some browsers

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm asking this question because I didn't find information on the web and this seems to be uncommon issue.  After a lot of trial and error I'm creating this answer for reference.

I'm using python which runs the ffmpeg command to convert an MP4 into WEBM file.  I noticed that some of the conversions didn't seek when displaying in the webpage but other webm files worked on the same server.  I was converting from two different machines.  The core problem was the ffmpeg command was using pipe during the conversion process on one machine and output directly to a file on the other.

Apparently doing this doesn't populate the duration attribute in the file but if I ran ffmpeg with the same switches, same order and output to a file on the system, the duration attribute would populate.

I was converting from MP4 to WEBM format using opus for the audio.  This issue might only impact certain file types, webm as an example and not others.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Don't pipe the output, just save to a file as part of the ffmpeg command. Open the file and do what you need to do with it.

Check if the duration attribute exists, use ffprobe.